# Howto extend an Controller in a Plugin - CakePHP

Tags: design-patterns, cakephp, plugins, extend, cakephp-2.1

This is a design-pattern question.

I'm working with CakePHP 2.1 and I'm writing a Plugin (the FooPlugin).
I'd like the Plugin to contain Controllers (and Models) that are extensions of Controllers in the App. For example: I have a `UsersController` in `app/Controller` which is extended in the FooPlugin as FooUsersController with some Foo-specific actions. *(I'm basically building multiple apps in the form of Plugins that all rely on one central User-management app)*

It is common practice (I presume) to have all Controllers in the Plugin extend the `FooAppController`. But I would like to bypass the FooAppController and let the FooUsersController extend the UsersController directly instead.
This breaks the possibility to use a Plugin-wide `beforeFilter` etc...

My questions:

- Does this break more than just Plugin-wide `beforeFilter` / `beforeRender`?
- Am I overlooking a common pattern to inherit functionality from both the FooAppController and the UsersController? Or should I deal with one choice or the other?
- Is what I propose a big no-no? Or perfectly alright as long as I'm aware of the pattern I follow?

Kind regards,
Bart

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the app controllers wihtout any problems, indeed there is no pluginwide callbacks anymore, you could add a component to the plugin controllers to handle plugin wide callbacks perhaps as solution for this and still keep your plugin controllers DRY

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `App::uses('MyController', 'MyPluginName.Controller');`

According to the docs from 2.0: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-files-from-plugins

Which says the following:

Loading classes in plugins works much the same as loading app and core classes except you must specify the plugin you are loading from:

```
// Load the class Comment in app/Plugin/PluginName/Model/Comment.php
App::uses('Comment', 'PluginName.Model');

// Load the class CommentComponent in
// app/Plugin/PluginName/Controller/Component/CommentComponent.php
App::uses('CommentComponent', 'PluginName.Controller/Component');
```